# Searching for Program to draw vertices

Tags: drawing, vector-graphics, 3d, opengl

I cant seem to find exactly what im looking for. I have a 3D triangle (x,y,z) vertices that i want to display on the screen. Im just looking for a simple online program that i can enter in (x,y,z),(x1,y1,z1) & (x2,y2,z2) and display a 3D triangle based on these vertices. Everything i find does 2D online. is there a 3D one ?